# How can we target java 7 with Scene builder 2?

Tags: java, javafx-2, compatibility, fxml, scenebuilder

We have Scene Builder 2 and the FXML it produces can cause errors with JavaFx from Java 7.  One big problem is the CSS @Style command.  Another seems to be ScaleShape.  But more, the colours on one AnchorPane completely failed under Java 7 but work OK with Java 8.

Is there a mode or option to invoke Scene Builder under Java 7 or get it to design Java 7 JavaFX compatible screen markup?

Are there other options for getting compatibility?

Comment: I have my doubts on Java 7 + JavaFX for production, as the development efforts seemed to go into the Java 8 version. Maybe XML postprocessing, keeping the SceneBuilder version and one Java 7 version, will be needed.

Comment: @JoopEggen ... I think you may be correct on both scores.  I worked on a production JavaFX project last year with Java 7, it was OK.  The trick might be to focus on the achievable.  An XSLT on incompatibilities would be lovely -- If someone on JavaFX can document them (or provide an XSLT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to target Java 7, use [SceneBuilder 1.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html), not SceneBuilder 2.  But as the download page I linked says in red letters "not recommended for use in production".  So I advise moving to Java 8 for JavaFX development.

Comment: As a one-off, Java 8 might be OK.  There's a lot of sites who will not want to move-off Java 7 (_for many reasons_).  Do the wise souls on JavaFX have a way for JavaFX 2 to co-exist with Java 7?  If not, the adoption could be retarded.

Comment: JavaFX 2 only works on Java 7.  SceneBuilder 2 is not targeting JavaFX 2 or Java 7, it targets Java 8 only.  If you want to use Java 7, just use SceneBuilder 1.1 which targets Java 7, it's not recommended in most cases, but it will still work if you need it.